# If a matrix is both Hermitian and unitary show all its eigen values are ±1

Tags: matrices

If a matrix is both Hermitian and unitary show all its eigen values are ±1.

How to proceed ? Have no idea

Thanks

Comment: What are you allowed to know/use? Do you know about (left/right) singular values (or equivalently SVD)?

Comment: Do you know what a Jordan normal form is?

Comment: No I dont know about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is unitary, then $A^{\dagger}A=I$ and if it is Hermitian then $A=A^{\dagger}$. You can clearly see that $AA=A^2=I$ then. Since $\lambda$ of $I$ is $1$, you have $A^2x=\lambda x=x$. Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: I suspect you meant $\lambda^2 x$ above?

Comment: Well $\lambda$ was the eigenvalue for $I$ but I could make that more clear

Answer (score 4):

If a matrix is unitary, then $\|Ux\| = \|x\|$ and so if $Ux= \lambda x$, we see that $|\lambda| = 1$.

If a matrix is Hermitian, its eigenvalues are real.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,you people almost did it for me